# Run sample randomly in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have three request in the plan, the third one in an put request.

If I have 30 virtual users, for instance, how can I run the third request (put) just few number of time in a random way?

```
Sample 1
Sample 2
Sample 3 ( put)
```

If I used 30 VU, I need the output be like:

```
Sample one - 30 hits
Sample 2 - 30 hits
Sample 3 - 5 hits ( random number), distributed over the test, 2 at the beginning, 1 at the middle and 2 at the end of the test - this is an example.
```

Answer (score 2):

The options are in:

1. [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - if you want to try to run a Sampler more or less frequently than the others
2. [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) - the same as 1 but if you need guarantee that the sampler will be executed at least once (you will need to come up with a proper "Switch Value"
3. [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide) - the same as 2 but it's easier to configure and use

Answer (score 1):

Put third sampler under [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html?#Throughput_Controller) with `Percent executions` with percentage defined in `Throughput` field

> Percent executions
> causes the controller to execute a certain percentage of the iterations through the test plan.